# How to quickly process images uploaded by user?

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, imagemagick

I was thinking of using imagemagick to process images uploaded by a user in various ways (creating new images that are scaled, have drop shadows, etc.) but I've been worried about the speed. I don't want the user staring at a loading gif forever.

So I started looking around to see how other sites do it and I found http://www.redbubble.com. Users upload artwork and almost instantly there are tons of variations of the image in the shop processed in various ways. What does it use to process and generate images so fast?

Comment: At a guess, they resample the image down to a thumbnail and play around with those, which will be very quick because they are very small. Then, when the user trys to view one of them, you apply the same effect to the larger image, and send it to the user. The other possibility is "a really powerful server".

Comment: Can you go to the page where you upload images, right click and goto "View Page Source" (that's how it is written in my Firefox), then see if there are any scripts included? They will look like <script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js">. That's probably how you would find out what they are using if it is a Javascript solution but I don't want to register for an account.

Comment: @DaveRandom - I'm able to directly access the various shop images via direct url, so when you upload the image, it creates each variation right then, not just when it's viewed (if that was what you were trying to say)

Comment: @Noah not necessarily, it may create them when you request the URL. Just because you have a "direct URL" does not mean it points to a file that actually exists, it may be re-written to point to a script.

Comment: @cillosis Other than some flash upload and jquery upload code, there isn't any other script code that I can see that relates to how it processes images to fast.

Comment: @DaveRandom - Oh, I see. Creating them on request. Does that work even when I change the file path of the image via firebug? Because I'm able to on Red Bubble. And do you know any articles about how to implement such a thing?

Comment: Cloud hosting is your best friend. Very high available processing power on demand and low cost - is that what would fit your task?

Answer (score 1):

- it's relatively hard and inconvenient to maintain client-side image processing (it would be some kind of flash app similar to www.picnik.com with limited functionality)
- I see use of ruby, nginx, remote xhr calls, json etc. that means that delayed_jobs/resque might be used to schedule asynchronous image processing using imagemagick, json/xhr to check the status. processed images are requested from ih*.redbubble.net (point to edgecastcdn.net) and seems like they produce them on the fly and let CDN cache them until user changes that image or it expires in the cache.
- they have ~800k monthly visitors, you don't want to put load on app/web servers to process images, there is either delayed_jobs or resque behind the scene or ih* (image host?) servers that produce images on the fly (there are 4 of them, but who knows how many behind virtual host/proxy configuration)
- all upload requests go to amazon (ec2, that might be a load balanced IP), originals are stored on amazon s3. they can scale by requesting more ec2 instances on demand.

hope you get an idea what's behind... back to your question: no client-side images processing, imagemagick is used, and there is a chance they do it on the fly.